# Dynamic sum/count condition while assignment

Tags: r

I have two data frames (**`table1`** and **`randomdata`**) with the following schema:

```
#randomdata
randomdata$cube = {1,5,3,3,4,5,5,2,2,6,1,2,....} (1000 rows)

#table1
table1$side = {1,2,3,4,5,6} (6 rows)
table1$frequency = NULL
```

I want to count the occurence from the different sides of the cube (of the first 10 rows from `randomdata$cube`) and assign the result to `table1$frequency` to the corresponding row (based on `table1$side`).

I can do this successfuly this way:

```
table1$frequency[1] <- sum(randomdata$cube[1:10] == 1)
table1$frequency[2] <- sum(randomdata$cube[1:10] == 2)
table1$frequency[3] <- sum(randomdata$cube[1:10] == 3)
... 
table1$frequency[6] <- sum(randomdata$cube[1:10] == 6)
```

This works very well, but there must be a better way.

Instead of 6 statements, I imagine something like this:

```
table1$frequency <- sum(randomdata$cube[1:10] == table1$side)
```

Can someone show me a more dynamic way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: wouldn't `table(randomdata$cube)` give what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with converting the 'cube' column to `factor` with `levels` specified as 1:6 and then do the `table`.  If we do it without that, missing elements can get dropped out of the `table` output.  Here, it would be `0` if a level is missing

```
table1$frequency <-  table(factor(randomdata$cube[1:10], levels = 1:6))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
randomdata %>%
    slice(1:6) %>%
    count(cube = factor(cube, levels = 1:6), .drop = FALSE) %>%
    pull(n)  %>%
    mutate(table1, frequency = .)
```

Comment: table1$frequency <-  table(factor(randomdata$cube[1:10], levels = 1:6)) did the job. Thank you. Now I have the problem, while plotting the data:

plot(table1$sides, table1$frequency, type="h").

The y-axis doesn't show numeric values. I think, this is because it is treated as a factor.

Comment: @Arber Please post as a new question

Comment: You can only post once every 90 minutes. :( (will do it later).

Comment: I post a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008324/y-axis-without-values-while-plotting-histogram-like-vertical-lines
Do you mean the new problem is too challenging?

Comment: I meant the time 90 minutes to post