# y-Axis without values while plotting histogram like vertical lines

Tags: r

I have a data frame (**`table1`**) with the following schema:

```
> table1

      sides frequency relFrequency
1         1         1          0.1
2         2         3          0.3
3         3         0          0.0
4         4         3          0.3
5         5         1          0.1
6         6         2          0.2

> summary(table1)
        sides    frequency   relFrequency
 Min.   :1.00   n.vars :1       n.vars :1  
 1st Qu.:2.25   n.cases:10      n.cases:1  
 Median :3.50                           
 Mean   :3.50                           
 3rd Qu.:4.75                           
 Max.   :6.00
```

I want to create a histograme like plot histogram:

```
plot(table1$sides, table1$relFrequency, type="h")
```

Unfortunately the y-Axis has no values. I think this is because `relFrequency` is treated as a factor. Can I convert the factor somehow to numeric?

Thank you.

//edit

```
> dput(table1)
structure(list(side = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), frequency = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Dim = 6L, class = "table"), relFrequency = structure(c(0.1, 
0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2), class = "table", .Dim = 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> str(table1)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ side: num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ frequency        : 'table' int [1:6(1d)] 1 3 0 3 1 2
 $ relFrequency : 'table' num [1:6(1d)] 0.1 0.3 0 0.3 0.1 0.2
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this code, I get y-axis values.  But I may not have the same data format as you.  Unfortunately,  you did not provide your actual data.  Please type `dput(table1)` and paste the output into your question so that we get exactly the same format as you are working with.

Comment: Please check the `str(table1)`  I am guessing `relFrequency` is not `numeric` class

Comment: I added the information to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this, it did work:

```
table1$frequency <- as.numeric(table1$frequency)
aufgabe1$relFrequency <- as.numeric(table1$frequency)
```